# Modifying DataGridView data C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have a datagridview to show what users are currently active. It selects the UserID and DeviceID from the ActiveUsers table.

I also have another table containing all the user's data and another table containing all the device's data. These ID's in the ActiveUser table are foreign keys of the other two tables.

Is there a way I could replace the data in the datagridviewcolumns with the relevant User and Device data selected from the other two tables?

For example rather than showing the UserID from the ActiveUsers table replace this with the Users FirstName + LastName, etc from the Users data table and replace DeviceID with DeviceName.

[image].

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve]. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Yes, are you familiar with using SQL joins to merge relational data?